# Trying to display mysql data which consists of several words in a single text field

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I've some data in mysql database which should be inserted to the form so user can edit it and resubmit again. But during insertion I'm facing following issue.

I've a table coloumn named "description" which consists of several words in one row. But when I select it and echo with php only first word is shown.

This is my code:

```
modify.html
<html>
<body>
<form action="modify.php" method="post">
<input type="text" name="acronym" id="acronym" value="">
<input type="submit" value="Search for acronym">
</form>
</body>
</html>

modify.php
<?php
$acronym = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['acronym']);

$sql_search="SELECT * FROM `acronym_table` WHERE `acronym` LIKE '$acronym'";

$result = $conn->query($sql_search);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<form action=\"save_modified.php\" method=\"post\">
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>ID</td>
                        <td><input type=\"text\" value=". $row["id"]. " id=\"id\"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Acronym</td>
                        <td><input type=\"text\" value=". $row["acronym"] ." id=\"acronym\"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Description</td>
                        <td><input type=\"text\" value=". $row["definition"]." id=\"definition\" style=\"width: 200px; padding: 2px; border: 1px solid black\"></td> 
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><input type=\"submit\" value=\"Modify\"></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </form>";
    }
} else{
    echo "0 results";
}

?>
```

In table row

```
<tr>
<td>Description</td>
<td><input type=\"text\" value=". $row["definition"]." id=\"definition\" style=\"width: 200px; padding: 2px; border: 1px solid black\"></td> 
</tr>
```

in "definition" text area I should show multiple words selected from DB.

Please, help.

Comment: can you post an extract of the data you have in the database? Maybe it is related to the content, in any case you should use htmlspecialchars($row["definition"]) to print a the value.

Comment: Output for that selected field from database is this value "Local Time of Descending Node". But when I do it like written above only "Local" is displayed in text area.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you forgot the double quotes when adding id, acronym, definition and so the browser ignores everything that comes after a space of your value.

That is why you can see the first word, everything else will be dropped by the browser since it is invalid html for it.

try this:

```
<tr>
                    <td>ID</td>
                    <td><input type=\"text\" value=\"". $row["id"]. "\" id=\"id\"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Acronym</td>
                    <td><input type=\"text\" value=\"". htmlspecialchars($row["acronym"]) ."\" id=\"acronym\"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Description</td>
                    <td><input type=\"text\" value=\"". htmlspecialchars($row["definition"])."\" id=\"definition\" style=\"width: 200px; padding: 2px; border: 1px solid black\"></td> 
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><input type=\"submit\" value=\"Modify\"></td>
                </tr>
```